# Using a splat to catch errors is not working

Tags: ruby, error-handling, rest-client, rescue, splat

I have a lot of errors that I need to catch, so I put them all into two arrays and made a constant to hold them, however, when I run the program I receive the exception:

```
C:/Users/thomas_j_perkins/bin/ruby/tool/sql_tool/whitewidow/lib/imports/constants_and_requires.rb:62:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant RestClient::MaxRedirectsReached (NameError)
        from whitewidow.rb:6:in `require_relative'
        from whitewidow.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

Here's how the constants look:

```
LOADING_ERRORS = [RestClient::ResourceNotFound, RestClient::InternalServerError, RestClient::RequestTimeout,
                RestClient::Gone, RestClient::SSLCertificateNotVerified, RestClient::Forbidden,
                OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError, Errno::ECONNREFUSED, URI::InvalidURIError, Errno::ECONNRESET,
                Timeout::Error, OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError, Zlib::GzipFile::Error, RestClient::MultipleChoices,
                RestClient::Unauthorized, SocketError, RestClient::BadRequest, RestClient::ServerBrokeConnection,
                RestClient::MaxRedirectsReached]
FATAL_ERRORS = [Mechanize::ResponseCodeError, RestClient::ServiceUnavailable, OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError,
                RestClient::BadGateway]
```

Here's how I'm using them:

```
begin
  # Do some cool stuff
rescue *FATAL_ERRORS => e
  puts e
end
```

--

```
begin
  # Do some more cool stuff
rescue *LOADING_ERRORS => e
  puts e
end
```

Am I doing something wrong to where I will receive a top required error? Just in case you need it here's the entire requiring file that the error is specifying:

```
# Built in libraries
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'rest-client'
require 'timeout'
require 'uri'
require 'fileutils'
require 'yaml'
require 'date'
require 'optparse'
require 'tempfile'
require 'socket'
require 'net/http'

# Created libraries
require_relative '../../lib/modules/format'
require_relative '../../lib/misc/credits'
require_relative '../../lib/misc/legal'
require_relative '../../lib/misc/spider'
require_relative '../../lib/modules/copy'
require_relative '../../lib/modules/site_info'
require_relative '../../lib/modules/expansion/string_expan'

# Modules that need to be included
include Format
include Credits
include Legal
include Whitewidow
include Copy
include SiteInfo

# Constants used throughout the program
=begin
USER_AGENTS = { # Temporary fix for user agents until I can refactor the YAML file
    1 => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; 008/0.83; http://www.80legs.com/webcrawler.html) Gecko/2008032620',
    2 => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; U; ABrowse 0.6; Syllable) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko)',
    3 => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3pre) Gecko/20100403 Lorentz/3.6.3plugin2pre (.NET CLR 4.0.20506)',
    4 => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Yahoo! Slurp; http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/ysearch/slurp)',
    5 => 'igdeSpyder (compatible; igde.ru; +http://igde.ru/doc/tech.html)',
    6 => 'larbin_2.6.3 (ltaa_web_crawler@groupes.epfl.ch)',
    7 => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.2; SAMSUNG SM-T550 Build/LRX22G) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/3.3 Chrome/38.0.2125.102 Safari/537.36',
    8 => 'Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0.1; Nexus Player Build/MMB29T)',
    9 => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1',
    10 => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)',
}
=end
FORMAT = Format::StringFormat.new
PATH = Dir.pwd
VERSION = Whitewidow.version
SEARCH = File.readlines("#{PATH}/lib/lists/search_query.txt").sample
USER_AGENTS = YAML.load_file("#{PATH}/lib/lists/rand-age.yml")
OPTIONS = {}
USER_AGENT = USER_AGENTS[rand(1..10)]
SKIP = %w(/webcache.googleusercontent.com stackoverflow.com github.com)
LOADING_ERRORS = [RestClient::ResourceNotFound, RestClient::InternalServerError, RestClient::RequestTimeout,
                RestClient::Gone, RestClient::SSLCertificateNotVerified, RestClient::Forbidden,
                OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError, Errno::ECONNREFUSED, URI::InvalidURIError, Errno::ECONNRESET,
                Timeout::Error, OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError, Zlib::GzipFile::Error, RestClient::MultipleChoices,
                RestClient::Unauthorized, SocketError, RestClient::BadRequest, RestClient::ServerBrokeConnection,
                RestClient::MaxRedirectsReached]
FATAL_ERRORS = [Mechanize::ResponseCodeError, RestClient::ServiceUnavailable, OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError,
                RestClient::BadGateway]
```

Comment: According to the error, you need to check the line `from whitewidow.rb:6:in 'require_relative'`, what does it require?

Comment: @BlueSmith it requires the above file with the requires, classes, modules, and constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed `mechanize` and `rest-client`

`gem install mechanize`
`gem install rest-client`

then I opened an IRB session

`require mechanize`
`require rest-client`

then tested you FATAL_ERROR array and was able to raise the error and handle it with your code.

So there is no problem with the way you are using the `*` splat operator.

The problem is in your `LOADING_ERRORS` array.

When I tried doing the same thing with your `LOADING_ERRORS` array, I got the same error message as you.

I cloned the `rest-client` git repository and searched in the `lib/restclient/exceptions.rb` file and it seems like there is no `RestClient::MaxRedirectsReached` defined.

If you remove that exception from your array, the code works.

After further research in the repository, there is a `history.md` file and it states:

> - Changes to redirection behavior: (#381, #484)
>
>   - Remove `RestClient::MaxRedirectsReached` in favor of the normal
>       `ExceptionWithResponse` subclasses. This makes the response accessible on
>       the exception object as `.response`, making it possible for callers to tell
>       what has actually happened when the redirect limit is reached.
>   - When following HTTP redirection, store a list of each previous response on
>       the response object as `.history`. This makes it possible to access the
>       original response headers and body before the redirection was followed.
>   - Follow redirection consistently, regardless of whether the HTTP method was
>       passed as a symbol or string. Under the hood rest-client now normalizes the
>       HTTP request method to a lowercase string.

So it seems like that exception has been removed from the `rest-client` library.

You may want to replace it with `RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse`

Comment: Two notes:
1. The `RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse` exception is the parent class for many of the exceptions that `rest-client` raises, no need to enumerate all of them.
2. Confusingly, `rest_client` is actually a different gem, a deprecated fork. https://rubygems.org/gems/rest_client https://rubygems.org/gems/rest-client